# Can the raml in API Manager be updated automatically in Cloudhub from Runtime Manager?

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio, cloudhub

Can I configure Anypoint Cloudhub so when a new version of the application is uploaded and deployed in Runtime Manager then the RAML file in API Manager is updated with the new version?

I have set up API auto discovery and the RAML is not being updated and I have looked at API sync in Anypoint Studio but this looks like it would need to be triggered manually whereas I'm looking to have it automated when the new version of the app is deployed in Runtime Manager

I'm using Anypoint Studio 6.2 and Mule 3.8.3

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've tested this and it works as designed. It will resolve the includes and will put the JSON in-line. Note, It was designed to quick upload small and simple RAMLs. For big and more complex files you will have to create the API through the API Manager in Anypoint Platform, and then upload all your files through it. Or you could do it by creating a new connection in the API Sync view.

For more information about API Sync, please check the following link: 
https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-studio/v/6/api-sync-reference

Please, have in mind that the files you will sync with API Sync, must be in src/main/api